# generate subsection of pandas rows on condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe like this-

```
identity    Line    Epoch   Day Seconds Date             Time   OffWrist_Actiware
111_&       1       1590    1   0      10/27/2013      13:15:00    0
111_&       2       1591    1   30     10/27/2013      13:15:30    0
111_&       3       1592    1   60     10/27/2013      13:16:00    0
111_&       4       1593    1   90     10/27/2013      13:16:30    0
111_&       5       1594    1   120    10/27/2013      13:17:00    0
111_&       6       1595    1   150    10/27/2013      13:17:30    0
111_&       7       1596    1   180    10/27/2013      13:18:00    0
111_&       8       1597    1   210    10/27/2013      13:18:30    0
111_&       9       1598    1   240    10/27/2013      13:19:00    0
```

Now based on some conditions I found the row which had value `13:15:00`in the `Time` column.Now I want to generate a new pandas dataframe which has all the subsequent rows after 13:15:00 upto the row which has the same date .

Comment: You want to extract the date of the row which had value 13:15:00, then use that  to subset your dataframe (something like ````df1 = df[df['Date']==date]````). Am I missing something here...?

Comment: I'm not clear what you mean in your question when you say "up to the row which has the same date". All the rows in your example have the same date! Did you mean "select all rows of the same date with a time value higher than `13:15:00`"?

Comment: @xyzjayne but in that case all the rows which has that date will be generated...I want only the rows starting from the time 13:15:00 date 10/27/2013 till the date 10/27/2013 gets over in the dataframe.

Comment: Use two conditions. `(df.Date == date_you_want) & (df.Time >= time_on_date_you_want)` and then subset based on that.

Comment: So you mean your data is not sorted based on Date and you want to extract only from this portion (where date is 10/27/2013 in a continuous fashion)? If so please edit your question.

Answer (score 1):

You need:

I took the liberty to add a dummy data with a new date.

`df`:

```
  identity  Line  Epoch  Day  Seconds        Date      Time  OffWrist_Actiware
0    111_&     1   1590    1        0  10/27/2013  13:15:00                  0
1    111_&     2   1591    1       30  10/27/2013  13:15:30                  0
2    111_&     3   1592    1       60  10/27/2013  13:16:00                  0
3    111_&     4   1593    1       90  10/27/2013  13:16:30                  0
4    111_&     5   1594    1      120  10/27/2013  13:17:00                  0
5    111_&     6   1595    1      150  10/27/2013  13:17:30                  0
6    111_&     7   1596    1      180  10/27/2013  13:18:00                  0
7    111_&     8   1597    1      210  10/27/2013  13:18:30                  0
8    111_&     9   1598    1      240  10/27/2013  13:19:00                  0
9    dummy    10   1599    2      300  10/28/2013  13:20:00
```

And then the code looks for the conditioned date and filters all rows after the `Time` specified in `row`.

```
df['Time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['Time'])
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
row = df.loc[df['Time']=='13:15:00']
df.loc[(df['Date'] == row['Date'].values[0]) & (df['Time']> row['Time'].values[0])]
```

Output:

```
  identity  Line  Epoch  Day  Seconds        Date      Time  OffWrist_Actiware
0    111_&     1   1590    1        0  10/27/2013  13:15:00                  0
1    111_&     2   1591    1       30  10/27/2013  13:15:30                  0
2    111_&     3   1592    1       60  10/27/2013  13:16:00                  0
3    111_&     4   1593    1       90  10/27/2013  13:16:30                  0
4    111_&     5   1594    1      120  10/27/2013  13:17:00                  0
5    111_&     6   1595    1      150  10/27/2013  13:17:30                  0
6    111_&     7   1596    1      180  10/27/2013  13:18:00                  0
7    111_&     8   1597    1      210  10/27/2013  13:18:30                  0
8    111_&     9   1598    1      240  10/27/2013  13:19:00
```

Comment: Are you sure that you have data after the time specified for the same date? The code works perfectly with the minified example that you provided.

Comment: so in the data there is a row generated after every 30 seconds in the time column...so in the example provided the the time starts at 13:15:00 right?..so the next is at 30 secs after and so on...till midnight and then the date changes to next day and time becomes midnight